# jQuery execution didn't work at window.resize?

Tags: jquery, resize, window, window-resize

I can see the log in chrome - it says wether over or under the specif width, but won't execute the code i have set properly … can you give me a hint please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    updateMenu();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        updateMenu();
    });
});
function updateMenu() {
    var size = $(window).width();
    if (size < 693) {
            $('body').addClass('js');
            var $menu = $('#menu'),
                $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
                $menuTrigger = $('.has-submenu > a');

            $menulink.click(function (e) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $menulink.toggleClass('active');
                $menu.toggleClass('active');
            });

            $menuTrigger.click(function (e) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
            });
            console.log('wsized under 693');
    }
    if (size > 693) {
            console.log('wsized over 693');
            //nothing
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't keep re-binding event handlers on resize... As the user resizes their browser, you continuously add more and more handlers on your elements. Keep track of a resolution breakpoint, and when that threshold is reached, bind/unbind your handlers.

Comment: Hello Chris, i am currently trying to solve this problem – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594454/how-to-link-a-listitem-with-submenu-in-multi-toggle-menu - on my own, maybe you can check it too? The jQuery above is my first try to fix the problem.